# WebStorm not compiling Angular TS code

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I am trying WebStorm IDE for Angular 2 Development. But stuck with irrelevant warnings/errors on TS files

**Below is the screenshot from WebStorm:**

[image]

I have tried setting TS compiler in

> File>Settings>Language&Frameworks>TypeScript and below is the screenshot

[image]

Kindly assist

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2016",
        "dom"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the errors are irrelevant?

Comment: because app is working on ng serve without any errors...

Comment: tried following this? https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/03/how-to-compile-typescript-in-webstorm/

Comment: post your tsconfig.json

Comment: Please provide relevant information in text form (example the errors) to make the question easier to search for.

Comment: Hi. Which IDE version do you use? You should try WebStorm 2017.1

Comment: Shall not it work in Webstorm 10 ?

Comment: I am not sure that WS10 can correctly work with angular 2 projects and typescript 2.X